# DoCmd OpenForm Where condition lands on NEW instead of the Key passed in Parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I add a record to a table called tbl_DISTR.  The primary key is DISTR_ID

A subform that is based on tbl_DISTR is sf_DISTR.  I requery it and can see the new value.

I use the textbox from sf_DISTR that holds the value to open a different version of the form (DISTRO) for additional processing.

Like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DISTRO", acNormal, , "COB_ID = " & Me!COB_ID & "  and distr_id = " & Me.DISTR_ID, acFormEdit
```

But the form says "NEW" in the DISTR_ID field.  Why did it jump there?

If I close main form and start over.  Form DISTRO is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it.  I ended up forcing a requery this way:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "DISTRO"
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "DISTRO"
```

Before opening the form with the where condition

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DISTRO", acNormal, , "DISTR_ID= " & Me.DISTR_ID
```

But it would be nice to know the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the last parameter, so try:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "DISTRO", acNormal, , "COB_ID = " & Me!COB_ID & " and distr_id = " & Me.DISTR_ID & ""
```

Comment: It didn’t make a difference. Not sure why closing the form and reopening makes a difference. I’ve also tried requeryjng the main form, but it doesn’t fix it until I manually close and open the main form.

Comment: Then you probably are missing values for one or both of the fields. That will filter out all records except the New, thus it lands there.

Comment: It could also land on new if it perceives the record is not there right?  Maybe that's why it fixes it when I close and reopen the main form. So i'm trying to figure out why the first subform  (sf_DISTR) can know about the value enough for me to click on it.  Then the other subform (DISTRO), does not see the value.  Both subforms exist on the same main form in different tabs.